# Background image resets after time (XAMPP)

Tags: images, xampp

So, i am hosting my own website with xampp and i installed wordpress and i had Bento Version: 1.6.5 as the theme.

Now, my background seems to be broken and it seems to remove its image from the background leaving it unselected and then i need to reselect the image from the gallery.

How do i keep my background image to stop reseting itself?

Note: The Background Image settings are not resetted, just the image selection. I am using a windows 10 pro computer. XAMPP Version is 3.2.2